# Example of a function with a oblique asymptote

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a simple function - maybe a a rational function; maybe a composition of a power function and a polynomial; maybe a composition of a rational function and a square root function - that is $0$ at $x=0$, that has an oblique asymptote $y=x$, and that intersects this asymptote at least once, not including at the origin.  The domain can be the interval $[0, \infty)$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Emilio Novati  The function  `$y = (x^{3} + 1)/(x^{2} + 1)$` that you offered nicely illustrates what I wanted, except that it is not 0 at 0.

Comment: I see! and this is the problem

Comment: @Emilio Novati   See the post from Chappers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take
$$ x + \frac{x}{1+x^2} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}, $$
where $p$ is a polynomial with as many roots as you require, and $q$ is a polynomial with degree larger than or equal to that of $p$, and no roots in the wrong places (in particular, none that coincide with roots of $p$, but you might want it to have no real roots as well). Then this intersects $y=x$ whenever $p(x)=0$, and has the other properties you require.

Comment: $x - a*Sin[x]*Exp[-b*x]$ for any $a\neq 0$ and any $b>0$...

Comment: It depends what the OP means by "simple".

Comment: @JeanMarie I said "a composition of a power function and a polynomial; maybe a composition of a rational function and a square root function.